# R dplyr: Non-Standard Evaluation difficulty. Would like to use dynamic variable names in filter and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have created a reproducible example to illustrate the problem I am having with non-standard evaluation in R (dplyr). I would like to use dynamic variable names in the scenario below:

```
# Given a data frame of patient data, I need to find records containing date logic errors.
# My datasets are enormous but here is a tiny example

patientData <- data.frame(
      patientID = 1:20,
      birth_d = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"),by = 90, length.out = 20),
      treat_d = seq(as.Date("2011-01-01"),by = 90, length.out = 20),
      death_d = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),by = 90, length.out = 20)
 )

# To create some random records that will be in error (death_d before birth_d, birth_d after treat_d, etc):

patientData$birth_d[5] <- as.Date("2017-01-01")
patientData$death_d[7] <- as.Date("2001-01-01")
patientData$treat_d[10] <- as.Date("2018-01-01")
patientData$birth_d[12] <- as.Date("2018-05-05")

# To determine which records have birth_d after death_d I could do the following:

badRecords <- patientData %>% filter(death_d < birth_d)

OR

badRecords <- patientData %>% mutate(dateDiff = death_d - birth_d) %>% filter(dateDiff < 0)

# But in my large application (with lots and lots of date variables) 
# I want to be able to use the date field names as *variables* and, using one date pair at a time,
# determine which records have dates out of sequence. For example,

firstDateName <- "birth_d"
secondDateName <- "death_d"

# I would like to do this, but it doesn't work
badRecords <- patientData %>% filter(!!firstDateName > !!secondDateName)

# This doesn't work... 
badRecords <- patientData %>% mutate(dateDiff = !!secondDateName - !!firstDateName) %>% filter(dateDiff < 0)

# Neither does this... it creates a dateDiff data frame.. with 20 duplicate records
badRecords <- patientData %>% mutate(dateDiff = .[secondDateName] - .[firstDateName]) %>% filter(dateDiff < 0)
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) rlang** Use `sym` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

firstDateName <- sym("birth_d")
secondDateName <- sym("death_d")
badRecords <- patientData %>% filter(!!firstDateName > !!secondDateName)
```

giving:

```
> badRecords
  patientID    birth_d    treat_d    death_d
1         5 2017-01-01 2011-12-27 2012-12-26
2         7 2011-06-25 2012-06-24 2001-01-01
3        12 2018-05-05 2013-09-17 2014-09-17
```

**2) Base R** or in base R:

```
firstDateName <- "birth_d"
secondDateName <- "death_d"
is.bad <- patientData[[firstDateName]] > patientData[[secondDateName]]
badRecords <- patientData[is.bad, ]
```

**2a) subset** Another base solution would be to replace the last two lines above with:

```
subset(patientData, get(firstDateName) > get(secondDateName))
```

Comment: Grumble grumble. I keep running into this (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) needlessly wordy article that doesn't actually tell much about how to do much every time I search for this and it doesn't even include this answer. Is there a proper tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `parse_expr` from `rlang`

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
patientData %>%
        filter(!! parse_expr(paste(firstDateName, ">", secondDateName)))
#   patientID    birth_d    treat_d    death_d
#1         5 2017-01-01 2011-12-27 2012-12-26
#2         7 2011-06-25 2012-06-24 2001-01-01
#3        12 2018-05-05 2013-09-17 2014-09-17
```